# How to send logs to different transports with Winston?

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I have different events happening in the system and want to log some of them to one file, and others to another one.

For example:

- server events like 'start', 'stop' would go to to 'server.log' with transport named 'ServerLogger'.
- User events 'login', 'logout', 'register' would be put in 'users.log' with UsersLogger
- Payments events like 'paid', 'rejected' would be in 'payments.log' with PaymentsLogger.

In the system I would run it like:

```
logger.log(ServerLogger, 'start');
logger.log(UsersLogger, 'login','john');
logger.log(PaymentsLogger, 'paid','100', 'john');
```

How do I make it work like this, so that when I want to log to some specific logger, it would be used?

Should I register each logger as a new winston instance like this?

```
const serverLogger = new winston.Logger()
const usersLogger = new winston.Logger()
const paymentsLogger = new winston.Logger()
```

Comment: As far as I know, yes, you will need different loggers. Alternatively, a hackish solution may be to build your own logger upon winston, declare all possible logger in it, and make a convenience method to print to the different transports.

Answer (score 2):

While it may not be the perfect solution, I found myself in a similar situation. I had different files that may or may not be active, managing different part of a app.

My solution was to make my "own" logger, based on winston. Since each source code file was in need of one logger who log to differents files, and a "common" files, I made a "generator" that I call instead of requiring winston directly:

log.js:

```
'use strict';

const util = require('util'),
    winston = require('winston'),
    config = require('./config.json');

//If I don't want to log in files and only in console
let testMode = (config.log.mode === 'test');

//"Common" log file
const fileTransport = new (winston.transports.File)({
        timestamp: true,
        name: config.log.all.file,
        filename: config.log.all.file,
        level: config.log.all.level
    }),
//"Common" error log file
    errorTransport = new (winston.transports.File)({
        timestamp: true,
        name: config.log.error.file,
        filename: config.log.error.file,
        level: 'error'
    });

//Logs are also sent in mongoDB, with the same schema as in the files
let mongoTransport = {},
    mongoErrorTransport = {};

if(!testMode) {
    //Add winston.transport.MongoDB
    require('winston-mongodb');

    mongoTransport = new (winston.transports.MongoDB)({
        name: 'all',
        host: config.log.db.host,
        safe: config.log.db.safe,
        collection: 'all',
        level: config.log.all.level,
        db: config.log.db.db
    });
    mongoErrorTransport = new (winston.transports.MongoDB)({
        name: 'error',
        host: config.log.db.host,
        safe: config.log.db.safe,
        collection: 'error',
        level: 'error',
        db: config.log.db.db
    });
}

function getTransports(file) {
    let transports = [];

//Log in the console
    transports.push(new (winston.transports.Console)({
        timestamp: true,
        level: config.log.all.level,
        formatter: (args) => {
            let d = new Date();
            return d.getFullYear() +
                    '/' + d.getMonth(), +
                    '/' + d.getDate(), +
                    ' ' + d.getHours(), +
                    ':' + d.getMinutes(), +
                    ':' + d.getSeconds(), +
                    ':' + d.getMilliseconds(), +
                    ' - ' + file +
                    ' - ' + args.level + 
                    ' -\t' + args.message + 
                    '\t' + util.inspect(args.meta);
        }
    }));

    if(testMode) {
        return transports;
    }

    let name,
        level,
        filename;

    transports.push(fileTransport);
    transports.push(errorTransport);
    transports.push(mongoTransport);
    transports.push(mongoErrorTransport);

//Module specific logs

    if(config.log[file] && config.log[file].file) {
        name = config.log[file].file;
    } else {
        name = file;
    }
    if(config.log[file] && config.log[file].level) {
        level = config.log[file].level;
    } else if(config.log.default && config.log.default.level) {
        level = config.log.default.level;
    } else {
        level = 'info';
    }
    if(config.log[file] && config.log[file].file) {
        filename = config.log[file].file;
    } else if(config.log.default && config.log.default.file) {
        filename = config.log.default.path + file + '.log';
    } else if(config.log.default && config.log.default.path) {
        filename = config.log.default.file;
    } else {
        filename = './log/' + file + '.log';
    }

//Module specific log file

    transports.push(new (winston.transports.File)(
        {
            timestamp: true,
            name: name,
            level: level,
            filename: filename
        }
    ));

//Module specific Mongo collection for logs

    transports.push(new (winston.transports.MongoDB)({
        name: 'mongo' + file,
        host: config.log.db.host,
        safe: config.log.db.safe,
        collection: file,
        level: level,
        db: config.log.db.db
    }));

    return transports;
}

//Generator
module.exports = (file) => {
    let transports = getTransports(file);
    return new (winston.Logger)({
        rewriters: [
            (level, msg, meta) => {
                meta.app = file + '.js';
                return meta;
            }
        ],
        transports: transports
    });
};
```

To be called like:

```
'use strict';

const Logger = require('./log.js'),
    logger = Logger('myModule');

logger.debug('Hi');
logger.error('Oops');
```

While it is far from a perfect solution, and may not be applicable to your specific problem, something similar may be cleaner than manually creating every logger.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a slightly different solution that works okay for what is similar but not matching problem. I want to send two log messages that the job was started and finished to cloudwatch, while doing a bunch more logging as the process runs that get handled differently. (the cloudwatch environment ties into our monitoring, we have a couple hundred jobs that report failure through cloudwatch).

So I just add and remove transports when I'm doing logs to cloudwatch:

```
function logSomethingForMonitoring(msg){
  try{
      parentLogger.add(cloudwatch)
      parentLogger.info(msg)
  } finally {
    parentLogger.remove(cloudwatch)
  }
}
```

I suspect this isn't super performant so it may be the best solution for normal logs, but seems to work fine if this isn't normal logging. Haven't really tested because like I said I only use it for two messages.